# Django - If statement with request.user

Tags: django, if-statement

I have a problem with an if-statement. I just want to check on a page if the user who requests the listing page is the same one as the user who won the listing on that page.

My view looks like this:

```
def show_closed_listing(request, listing_id):
    closed_listing = InactiveListing.objects.get(id=listing_id)
    field_name = "winning_user"
    winning_user = getattr(closed_listing,field_name)
    message = False
    print(request.user)
    print(winning_user)
    if request.user == winning_user:
        print("This is good")
        message = "You have won this listing!"
    else:
        print("Not good")
    return render(request, "auctions/closed_listing.html", {
        "closed_listing" : closed_listing,
        "message" : message
    })
```

When I visit a page, signed in as Test2, when Test2 has won the listing, my terminal shows as follows:

- Test2
- Test2
- Not good

[As also can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUKUk.png)

**I don't get why request.user and winning_user look the same, but the if-statement is false?**

If needed, here is my model:

```
class InactiveListing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=512, default="")
    winning_user = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    winning_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0.01)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: what data are you storing in respective to the winning_user field in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`winning_user` is not a User instance. It would be the username, or ID, or any field, but not a User. You'd need a ForeignKey for that.

Try comparing:

```
winning_user == request.user.username: # Or winning_user == str(request.user) if you've edited the __str__ method like below.
```

They look the same, because I'm guessing you have this on your user model:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

Comment: Yes, he is comparing char field with foreign key field.

Comment: @ShiBilPK request.user is  not a `foreignkey` field. It's a `User` class' instance